# Can I run more than two kernels simultaneously on my MacBookAir laptop?

Tags: parallelization, kernel, version-10

I'm running Version Number 10.0.1.0 with Platform
Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit kernel).

I have two Mathematica programs running using "Local" and 
"Alternative Local Kernel".

Is this the most I can use? (I did try adding a third ["New"], but there
seemed to be a licensing issue.)

Comment: Since you suspected it could be a licensing issue, it would make sense to tell us what license you have.

Answer (score 3):

You can run as many kernels at the same time as your license allows.  Your hardware does not matter.

Run

```
FilterRules[SystemInformation["Kernel"], "MaxLicenseProcesses" | "MaxLicenseSubprocesses"]
```

to find out the number.

"MaxLicenseProcesses" refers to main kernels—what you are looking at in the kernel configuration options.

"MaxLicenseSubprocesses" refers to subkernels—what you use with the parallel tools ([`Parallelize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelize.html)).

Comment: Possibly the kernel for the frontend also counts, so that if you have a frontend then you can run "MaxLicenseProcesses" minus one kernels.

Comment: @C.E. It does not count.

Comment: Then I don't know how to explain this: the code gives `"MaxLicenseProcesses" -> 8` but if I start four different versions of *Mathematica* (say 10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3 and 10.4) I [cannot start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOdPl.png) a fifth version (e.g. 11.0). If the frontend kernel does not count, then I should be able to start eight versions of *Mathematica*.

Comment: Thanks--will try the suggestion (when either of my two currently running kernels terminates), Szabolics. I take it that licenses vary on the number allowed--no standard one for my version?. I only have one version at hand, not the several that C. E. appears to have. Well I did add a ["New"] kernel, but then when I tried to run it I got a licensing notice. So, maybe I'm limited to 2 (I don't know how "front end" considerations enter here.)

Comment: @C.E. What is `SystemInformation["FrontEnd", "MaxLicenseProcesses"]` on your machine? I can run 6 versions concurrently with front ends.  I can also run 7 (not 6) kernels in the terminals *after* having started a Front End (with its 2 kernels). The 8th one fails.  I seem to have a license that allows 8 kernel and 8 front ends to run simultaneously.

Comment: `SystemInformation["FrontEnd", "MaxLicenseProcesses"]` is also 8. This is why I said "possibly" in my original comment, I really wasn't sure what happened. Either way, you have convinced me that you are right. I tried to figure out what I am supposed to have with a student license and [this](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/pricing/students-individuals.php) page says I'm supposed to have four. Probably `"MaxLicenseProcesses"` is just wrong.

Comment: @C.E. Perhaps you have multiple licenses in your mathpass file and different ones get picked up?  Have you also tried running kernels in the terminal?  Can you only run 4 that way?

Comment: I asked this question--but now it seems that Mathematica objects to my using even a second kernel--telling me the "kernel was not able to start due to licensing terms".

Comment: @PaulB.Slater It depends on the specific setup. I believe some universities use a license server which allows running only a certain number of kernels in total at your institution. Thus if at a certain time too many people are using Mathematica at the same time, you may not be able to start it at all. Your IT department should have let you know if this is the case. If the licenses are local to your computer, then it is possible that some kernels are still running in the background (perhaps due to an error), and that's why you can't start more. The easiest way to ensure this isn't happening...

Comment: @PaulB.Slater ... is to reboot your computer.

Comment: Thanks, Szabolcs. I did reboot the machine. Seems OK presently. I should have noted that the machine in question is my personal (and not a departmental/university) one.

Comment: @PaulB.Slater Maybe you had more kernels running than you knew about. Occasionally (not very often), I have seen some stuck "zombie kernels", kernel processes that are not functional but failed to quit properly. At least on OS X there is no indication whatsoever that these are still running (unless you look for them with a process monitor). If this is indeed the case, and you don't want to reboot the computer, you can try killing these manually (on OS X you could use Activity Monitor and look for WolframKernel processes).

Comment: Well, I had only two kernels ("Local" and "Alternative Local") explicitly set up.

Comment: @PaulB.Slater What I described is not related to how many you have set up. In some unlucky situations a kernel simply fails to quit, so when you believe that you just restarted it, in fact you ended up with two (but one is uselessly stuck and running in the background).

Comment: Typically, I don't "restart" the machine, but use Quit Kernel. So, even if this command does not "take" for some reason, I would think that when I tried to use the quitted kernel again, Mathematica should go into some hold status, rather than give me a licensing problem prompt. But maybe there is something here, because the problem (I should document it better) seems to be associated with a certain order of use of the kernels. But if things persist, I'll certainly restart the machine--which did seem to be a successful strategy (at least at first).